# GPS implementation: provider enabled

Tags: android, gps, location

I try to implement a gps application, (I take the code from a guide) but doesn't work!
I think the problem is the provider enabled, so the app can't calculate the latitude and longitude.
Please help me, thank you.

```
package it.wstech.gps;


import java.util.Date;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;







public class GPSMainActivity extends Activity {

    private String providerId= LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

    private LocationListener myLocationListener= new LocationListener(){

        //methods of Location Listener interface

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged (String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
            if (status==LocationProvider.AVAILABLE){
                setTextViewValue(R.id.available,"TRUE");
               }
            else  {
                setTextViewValue(R.id.available,"FALSE");
                }


            }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled (String provider){
            setTextViewValue(R.id.enabled,"TRUE");
        }


        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled (String provider){
            setTextViewValue(R.id.enabled,"FALSE");
        }


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged (Location location){
            updateLocationData(location);
        }

    };






    //activity methods
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedIstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedIstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpsmain);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        setTextViewValue(R.id.provider,providerId);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService (LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationProvider provider= locationManager.getProvider(providerId);

        if (provider== null) {
            setTextViewValue (R.id.available,"FALSE");
        } else {
            setTextViewValue (R.id.available,"TRUE");
            boolean gpsEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(providerId);
            if (gpsEnabled){
                 setTextViewValue (R.id.enabled,"TRUE");   
                 }
             else {

                 setTextViewValue (R.id.enabled,"FALSE");
                 }

            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (location !=null){
            updateLocationData(location);
            }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providerId, 5, 1,myLocationListener); 
    }
}


    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
    }
    private void setTextViewValue (int textViewId, String value){
        TextView testView=(TextView) findViewById(textViewId);
        if (testView!=null){
            testView.setText(value);
        }
    }
    private void updateLocationData(Location location){
        Date timestamp= new Date (location.getTime());
        setTextViewValue (R.id.timestamp, timestamp.toString());
        double latitude=location.getLatitude();
        setTextViewValue (R.id.latitude, String.valueOf(latitude));
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        setTextViewValue (R.id.longitude, String.valueOf(longitude));
        if (location.hasAltitude()){
            double altitude = location.getAltitude();
            setTextViewValue (R.id.altitude, String.valueOf(altitude)); 
        }
        if (location.hasSpeed()){
            float speed=location.getSpeed();
            setTextViewValue(R.id.speed, String.valueOf(speed));
        }
    }
}
```

My activity_gpsmain.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ScrollView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableRow 
                 android:padding="5px">

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="Provider"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/provider"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>


                <TableRow 
                 android:padding="5px">

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="Disponibile"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/available"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow 
                 android:padding="5px">

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="Abilitato"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="@+id/enabled"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow 
                 android:padding="5px">

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="Timestamp"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow 
                 android:padding="5px">

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="Latitudine"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/latitude"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow 
                 android:padding="5px">

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="Longitudine"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="@+id/longitude"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow 
                 android:padding="5px">

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="Altitudine"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="@+id/altitude"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow 
                 android:padding="5px">

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="Velocità"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView 
                        android:text="@+id/speed"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

my AndroidManifest.xml:

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="it.wstech.gps"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-permission android:name ="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".GPSMainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Result:

- Provider gps

  Disponibile TRUE

  Abilitato false

  Timestamp

  Latitudine

  Longitudine false

  Altitudine false

  Velocità false

Comment: you'll need internet access permission in the manifest

Comment: have to give permission of course location

Comment: I add this ROW in manifest, but doesn't work anyway:       <uses-permission android:name ="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Answer (score -1):

### Try this code and get latitude and longitude

**Create a class GPSTracker.java**

```
package com.example.gpstracker;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener
{
private final Context _context;

boolean isGPSEnabled=false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled=false;
boolean canGetLocation=false;

Location location;
double latitude;
double longitude;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES=5; //5 meters
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES=1000*60*1; // 1 minute

protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context contet)
{
    this._context=contet;
    getLocation();
}




public Location getLocation() 
{
    try
    {
        locationManager =(LocationManager)_context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //getting GPS Status
        isGPSEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        //getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            this.canGetLocation=true;
            //first get location from network provider
            if(isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.i("Network","Network");

                if(locationManager !=null)
                {
                    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if(location !=null)
                    {
                        latitude=location.getLatitude();
                        longitude=location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/log
            if(isGPSEnabled)
            {
                if(location == null)
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.i("GPS","GPS Enabled");
                    if(locationManager !=null)
                    {
                        location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if(location !=null)
                        {
                            latitude=location.getLatitude();
                            longitude=location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location;
}
 public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }
public double getLatitude()
{
    if(location !=null)
    {
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
    }
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude()
{
    if(location !=null)
    {
        longitude=location.getLongitude();
    }
    return longitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation()
{
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void showSettingAlert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
    alert.setTitle("GPS is Setting");
    alert.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings..?");
    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        _context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

**Create your activity class file MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.gpstracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btnClick;
GPSTracker tracker;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnClick=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    tracker=new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());

    if(tracker.canGetLocation())
    {
        double latitude=tracker.getLatitude();
        double longitude=tracker.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"your Location is \n Latitude : " + latitude +
                "\n Longitude : "+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        tracker.showSettingAlert();
    }
}
}
```

**Add below lines in manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```